# No puedo enviar ya ni el hotmail

Tags: c#

Hace meses me funcionaba este programa por gmail, antes tenía que configurar este enlace activado para que puedas enviar mensajes desde la consola C#. Luego probé por hotmail, también me funcionaba, ni uno ni otro.

En gmail había que poner este enlace.
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

En hotmail, no había que modificar nada.

En este ejemplo pongo ahora hotmail.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código Consola para el hotmail.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;

namespace Enviar_email_Consola_08
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            // Variables.
            string usuario, contraseña, destinatario, asunto, mensaje;
            const int MAXIMA_LONGITUD = 40000;

            #region Configuración ventana.
            // Título de la ventana y versión del .Net usando.
            Console.Title = "Gestor correo electrónico Hotmail. "
                + typeof(string).Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion;

            // Tamaño de la ventana, x, y, o ancho y alto.
            const byte ancho = 80;
            const byte alto = 25;
            Console.SetWindowSize(ancho, alto);

            // Color de fondo.
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

            // Color de las letras.
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;

            // Limpiar pantalla y dejarlo todo en color de fondo.
            Console.Clear();

            // Visible el cursor.
            Console.CursorVisible = true;
            #endregion

            // Título del programa.
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tEnviar Correo Electrónico");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t----------------------------------------");

            try
            {

                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("\t\tTu correo electrónico: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                usuario = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("\t\tIntroducir contraseña: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                contraseña = LeerPassword();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("\t\tDestinatario: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                destinatario = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("\t\tAsunto: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                asunto = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("\t\tMensaje: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                //mensaje = Console.ReadLine();

                #region Enviar más de 255 caracteres.
                // #########################################################################
                Stream entradaDeDatos = Console.OpenStandardInput();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[MAXIMA_LONGITUD];
                int numerosBytesLeidos = entradaDeDatos.Read(buffer, 0, MAXIMA_LONGITUD);
                char[] chars = Console.InputEncoding.GetChars(buffer, 0, numerosBytesLeidos);
                mensaje = new string(chars);
                // #########################################################################
                #endregion

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
                Console.Write("\t\tCantidad de texto introducido: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.WriteLine(mensaje.Length);

                MailMessage correo = new MailMessage(usuario, destinatario, asunto, mensaje)
                {
                    // Enviar textos con tildes.
                    BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
                };

                SmtpClient servidor = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com")
                {
                    Port = 25 // 25 ó 465.
                };
                NetworkCredential credenciales = new NetworkCredential(usuario, contraseña);
                servidor.Credentials = credenciales;
                servidor.EnableSsl = true;

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("\t\tEnviando correo...");
                servidor.Send(correo);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t¡Correo enviado satisfactoriamente!");
                correo.Dispose();
                Console.CursorVisible = false;
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: \n");
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t" + ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("\t\tNo se ha enviado el correo.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }

        // A la hora de introducir la contraseña, se sustituye por asterístos (*) en pantalla.
        public static string LeerPassword()
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int contador = 0;

            do
            {
                cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {

                    sb.Append(cki.KeyChar);
                    if (contador < 1)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                    contador++;
                }

                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            } while (true);
            Console.WriteLine();
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

¿Alguna idea para corregir solucionar el problema?

Al menos quiero saber si realmente se puede vovler a enviar email con tu propio programa o ya los servidores de ellos tanto como gmail y hotmail no les da la gana de dejarnos.

Comment: Una recomendacion ENORME.. si haces un try catch, que el mismo no devuelva solo, ocurrio un error. Eso, no sirve absolutamente de nada. Si no sabes como controlar un error, no lo controles, deja que el sistema tire el error, asi sabemos que pasa realmente. Saca el try catch, y pone el error completo que sale, asi sabemos que pasa.

Comment: Lo hice y me da 2 errores que dice: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'Error al enviar correo.'
Y el otro error dice: SocketException: Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:25

Comment: Muy bien!!! ahora tenes un error desde el cual trabajar.. no conecta con el servidor SMTP... estas seguro que el servidor SMTP es correcto?

Comment: Si te refieres a este smtp.live.com. Hace meses lo era.